# Getting Undefined / Null value in async function while using useEffect React Native

Tags: react-native, asynchronous, react-hooks

Am I doing anything wrong here ?

If I console.log value outside sync function then its getting printed, but inside async function its null

1st time Screen load = no result
2nd time if ctrl + s = getting values

```
  const {un1} = useSelector(state => state.redusername);
  const {ps1} = useSelector(state => state.redpassword);

  const [user, setUser] = useState([]);

 const loadowndetails = async () => {
    try {
      const resp = await Axios.post(
        'https://example.com/owndetailshomepage.php',
        {
          un: un1,
          un: ps1,
        },
      );
      
      setUser(resp.data.phpresult);
    } catch (err) {
      // Handle Error Here
      console.error(err);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    loadowndetails();
  }, []);
```

1st time Screen load = no result
2nd time if ctrl + s = getting values

Comment: what value are you trying to print? `user` or `resp.data.phpresult`?

Comment: @AndersonVanzo I am trying to print user, actually in first attempt loadowndetails function getting null values, because of usetstate, how to get rid of that ?

Comment: the new value of `user` will only be available after the function ends, this is how useState works, if you need to use this value on that function, you need to store `resp.data.phpresult` in a local variable instead of a state (or use `resp.data.phpresult` itself)